# Unable to get text of an element

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

I have selenium Test case to validate contents of 2 web pages. The issue, I am facing is I'm not able to get anything from `element.getText()`.

I'm using below code.

```
driver1.get("https://some url");
String b = driver1.findElement(By.className("supArticleContent")).getText();
WebDriver driver2 = new ChromeDriver();  
driver2.get("https://some other url");
String a = driver2.findElement(By.className("supArticleContent")).getText();
System.out.println("text content is"+a);

if (a.equals(b)) {
     System.out.println("TC PASSED");          
 }
 else{
     System.out.println("TC FAILED");
   }
```

Comment: What is the HTML for the `supArticleContent`?

Comment: you should try some other locator instead of class name there are less chances for this to be unique on webpage

Comment: please fix your code formatting..

Comment: It's also possible that you are confusing `.getText()` with .`getAttribute("value")` but I can't tell because of a lot of missing information.

Comment: @NarendraR, your comment reads like a good beginning to a good answer.

Comment: Try to share the HTML code also. If you are trying to get a text from a editable field it wont work like this.

Answer (score 1):

1. if html code is `<div value="your expected text">`

   try: `element.getAttribute("value")`
2. if html code is `<div>your expected text<div>`

   try `element.gettext();`
   or  `element.getAttribute("innerHTML");`

   I met one fail case by gettext() but it worked by getAttribute("innerHTML")

div is just a tag name used for example, it can be any tag name as you may already know.

Answer (score 0):

This can have following reasons:

- Either the element cann't be located with the following locators you have given
- In the second line you have mentioned `driver2` for accessing the second website but you have mentioned `driver1.findElement(By.className("supArticleContent")).getText();`.

Try **Syso** after getting the text and storing in a variable. Then you will be able to debug this problem.

Comment: you may want to update your answer, the OP has edited their question to make use of `driver2`